# Is there any way to add a string value to an interger?

Tags: python, string

I want to make `MOVE_DISTANCE` equal 3 plus the amount of kills there are. I tried to change some things but it still didn't work.

```
MOVE_DISTANCE = 3 + str(kills)
MOVE_DISTANCE = 3 + kills
MOVE_DISTANCE = 3 + (kills)
```

**EDIT :** I know `str` and `int` can't be added together but I wanted to know if there was any way to do it like change the `str` into an `int` and then adding them both but I doubt `int(kills_int) = str(kills)` will work.

**EDIT AGAIN :** Here's the whole program in case you needed it

```
import pgzrun
import math
import random

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
CENTER_X = WIDTH/2
CENTER_Y = HEIGHT/2
CENTER = (CENTER_X, CENTER_Y)
FONT_COLOR = (255, 0, 0)
kills = 0
MOVE_DISTANCE = 5
game_over = False
first_spawn = True

fly = Actor("fly")

def draw():
    screen.clear()
    fly.draw()
    draw_counters(kills)

def place_fly():
    global first_spawn
    if first_spawn:
        fly.x = CENTER_X
        fly.y = CENTER_Y
        first_spawn = False
    else:
        fly.x = random.randint(0, 800)
        fly.y = random.randint(0, 600)

def draw_counters(kills):
    screen.draw.text("kills " + str(kills), fontsize=40, center=CENTER, color=FONT_COLOR)

def update():
           #DIAGONALS
    if keyboard.right and keyboard.down:
        fly.x += MOVE_DISTANCE/1.5
        fly.y += MOVE_DISTANCE/1.5
        if fly.x > WIDTH:
            fly.x = WIDTH
        if fly.y > HEIGHT:
            fly.y = HEIGHT
    elif keyboard.left and keyboard.down:
        fly.x -= MOVE_DISTANCE/1.5
        fly.y += MOVE_DISTANCE/1.5
        if fly.x < 0:
            fly.x = 0
        if fly.y > HEIGHT:
            fly.y = HEIGHT
    elif keyboard.right and keyboard.up:
        fly.x += MOVE_DISTANCE/1.5
        fly.y -= MOVE_DISTANCE/1.5
        if fly.y < 0:
            fly.y = 0
        if fly.x > WIDTH:
            fly.x = WIDTH
    elif keyboard.left and keyboard.up:
        fly.x -= MOVE_DISTANCE/1.5
        fly.y -= MOVE_DISTANCE/1.5
        if fly.y < 0:
            fly.y = 0
        if fly.x < 0:
            fly.x = 0
            #STRAIGHTS
    elif keyboard.right:
        fly.x += MOVE_DISTANCE
        if fly.x > WIDTH:
            fly.x = WIDTH
    elif keyboard.left:
        fly.x -= MOVE_DISTANCE
        if fly.x < 0:
            fly.x = 0
    elif keyboard.down:
        fly.y += MOVE_DISTANCE
        if fly.y > HEIGHT:
            fly.y = HEIGHT
    elif keyboard.up:
        fly.y -= MOVE_DISTANCE
        if fly.y < 0:
            fly.y = 0

def on_mouse_down(pos):
    global kills
    if fly.collidepoint(pos):
        kills += 1
        place_fly()

place_fly()

pgzrun.go()
```

Comment: What type of object `kills` refers to?

Comment: I think its a string because earlier in the code I wrote `kills = 0`

Comment: `str` and `int` aren't supposed to be added up. But is there any other way to increase the 
`MOVE_SPEED` for every kill.

Comment: `kills` is an `str`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the question. You see, I'm very new to programming and I just put the whole code my last edit in case you needed it.

Comment: If `kills` is a string and you want to add it to a number you can change it to a number with `int(kills)` or `float(kills)`.

Comment: Or I'm just really stupid and could increase the `MOVE_DISTANCE` directly while defining `on_mouse_down(pos)` Thank you still.

Comment: What’s wrong with MOVE_DISTANCE = kills + 3

Comment: kills is a string so it can't be added to`MOVE_DISTANCE` which is an interger

Comment: @Swagtonio-- Setting `kills = 0` makes kills an int, NOT a string.  You can use [type](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-type-function/) to check the variable type of kills.

Comment: From the code that you posted kills is always an int.

Comment: Well thanks, I'll try to make less mistakes and I'll make sure I know what variable type I have